# How does this formula $A\lor (A\to B)$ relate to intuitionistic logic?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, constructive-mathematics, intuitionistic-logic, sequent-calculus

It is my first approach to the proof theory of intuitionistic logic and I am considering a single-conclusioned Gentzen-style sequent calculus for it, namely $\bf G3i$ (Negri, Von Plato, *Structural Proof Theory*, p. 28).

By applying root-first the rules of $\bf G3i$, it turns out that the formula $A\lor (A\to B)$ is not derivable.

I understand the motivation behind the rejection of other laws such as ($A\lor \neg A$) or ($\neg\neg A\to A$), but I am struggling to see the point with $A\lor (A\to B)$.

Why is this the case? Are there some specific discussions in the literature fixing this?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 6):

Assume that it is derivable and replace $B$ with $\bot$.

What you get is $A \lor (A \to \bot)$ contradicting the underivability of LEM.

Comment: Thank you. It was definitely easier than I thought.